# How to get the scheme when no http:// or https:// is being specified?

Tags: php, http, url, https

I would like for users to be able to enter their company website URL in their company setup dialog, but I need to validate that. Apart from the typical sanitization functions, I would like to check if the URL scheme is `http://` or `https://` without the assumption the user has already entered it.

My function already parses the entered url to detect the scheme with a regex, but I would like to (ideally) check the URL from the server ala file_get_contents or parse_url and get the scheme, but I don't know how could I do it.

Comment: Why would this matter? Assume http. If it's https the server will redirect you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). The scheme will be returned in the `scheme` element of the array.

**Edit 1**

> Partial URLs are also accepted, `parse_url()` tries its best to parse them correctly.

If the scheme is not present in the URL, then the `scheme` element will be missing.

**Edit 2**

As @BenediktOlek says, you can use cURL to query the server:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array(
    $curl,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://www.example.com/',
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => TRUE,  // Output the response headers
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  // Return output as a string
        CURLOPT_NOBODY         => TRUE   // Use request method "HEAD"
    )
);
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

If the server requires an HTTPS connection, and is correctly configured, then it should return a `Location:` header with an HTTPS URL.

Comment: No, I already checked that. If, for example, you happen to run `parse_url("www.someurl.com");` the only thing you'll get in the return array is the `path` component, but no scheme is returned :P

Comment: well if there isn't a scheme om the string, then the best you can do is make an assumption and set one as a default.

Comment: I like the cURL approach. I'm going to test it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Too much information returned but it's a decent approach. I think I'll use the `no scheme -> http://` rule, but thanks to both for the cURL suggestion :)

Comment: @JulioMecaHansen You can do `explode("\n", $curlData)` to split cURL's response into an array, and then use a `foreach()` loop to find the `Location:` header in that array. Then `explode(':', $strHeader)` to extract the URL, and `parse_url()` to get the scheme.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `cURL` module to query the Server. But I guess it is safe to assume http. A proper configured webserver should redirect if http is not allowed.

[More on cURL here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 1):

Using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) with parameter `PHP_URL_SCHEME` like this:

```
$scheme = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
if( !in_array( $scheme, array( 'http', 'https'))){
  // Wrong URL
}
// Good URL
```

#### After comment:

```
if( strncmp( $url, 'http://', 7)){ // 7 = strlen( 'http://')
  // Not secured
} else if (strncmp( $url, 'https://', 8)) {
  // Secured
} else if ( strpos($url, '://') !== false){
  // ftp://, sftp:// and other protocols
  // you may do this also by: preg_match and regexp ~^[\w]+://~i - will be more accurate
} else {
  // any other URL, www.google.com and so on...
  // auto-assue: not secured
}
```

Comment: No, it's not working. Moreover, I tried it with several combinations, `www.someurl.com`, `http://www.google.com` and `https://www.google.com`, with `false`, `http` and `https` being the answers I got, but that's now what I want.

I mean, the user can insert a malformed URL but I still need to check if it's under a secure or non-secure connection, just to update their database record with a properly formatted URL.

Am I aiming too high with my intention?

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe this helps?

```
    NSRange range = [urlName rangeOfString:@"http://"];
//NSLog(@"found or not found");
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    //NSLog(@"range is found");
    //range.location is start of substring
    //range.length is length of substring
} else
{
    //NSLog(@"range is not found");
    //urlName = @"http://"  urlName;
    //NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Hello", @"World"];
    urlName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://",urlName];
    //NSLog(@"NEW urlName......%@", urlName);
}
```